# Insert dynamically created HtmlControl into declatatively established asp control

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

So I guess this is easy for those of you who have been doing this for a while.
I have a master page with 3 content panels. I have a page built on that master page. I have a table that I create in code behind to display the images. The number of images varies do does the size of the table. I need to insert this table into contentPanel2. The table is generated (instantiated) in code behind. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Suprisingly no one answered. Add asp panel to aspx, name it and use add() method of that panel to insert new controls into it.